# getting Uncaught SoapFault exception when using soap client

Tags: php, api, wsdl, asmx, soap-client

PHP Version: 5.3.3

I'm using the SOAP extension to pull data from a web api. Below you can see my connection details. When it gets to line 3 I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.global1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://www.global1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.wsdl" in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ATAPI\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ATAPI\index.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://www.glo...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ATAPI\index.php on line 5
```

Here are my connection details:

```
$wsdl = 'https://www.global1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.wsdl';
$loginarray = array('login' => "billy.jones@networkroi.co.uk", 'password' => "******", 'uri'=>"http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_2/", 'location'=>"https://global1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.asmx");
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $loginarray);
```

I've googled and see that it's possibly a bug with the soap extension?

I've uncommented:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

In the php.ini file. and I've also made sure my allow url fopen is set to on:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Anyone got an idea how I get get round this problem? Maybe I've forgotten to do something?

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you post a question on the Autotask CommunITy website (community.autotask.com) since there are a lot of resources there who are very familiar with Autotask-specific things.

The URL you are using isn't correct for WebServices access. If you use https://webservicesg1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.wsdl does it work?

Travis

Answer (score 0):

1) It works fine for me. I can load that and even do not need the password. Well, the problem occurs in some PHP/Soapclient versions. I advise you to upgrade the PHP to the latest version.

2) If it still does not work for you, try [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). It's pretty awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you believe there is a file with a .wsdl extension sitting around somewhere? To get the WSDL out of an ASMX web service, append "?wsdl" to the end of the service, e.g., https://global1.autotask.net/atservices/1.2/atws.asmx?wsdl.